# Using Jenkins and cygwin on windows node triggered job by GitHub

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, cygwin

I have a Jenkins machine and a Windows slave node.
On the windows machine I use Cygwin and the sshd from it to connect to the Jenkins master. On this slave I am trying to run a job which is started when something is pushed on Git.
In Cygwin I also have ssh-agent started.
Using Cygwin I can manually clone a project from Git. The connection between the master and Windows slave works fine as I am able to run other Jenkins jobs (which don't use git).

```
Building remotely on qa_s_02_w (qa) in workspace D:\jenkins_jobs\workspace\job_1
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:project_name.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:project_name.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:project_name.git
```

I also tried to setup a windows git command (I thought maybe the paths in linux version aren't recognised) but I got the similar result:

```
Building remotely on qa_s_02_w (qa) in workspace /cygdrive/d/jenkins_jobs/workspace/job_1
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@github.com:project_name.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:project_name.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:project_name.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:763)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1012)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1043)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1275)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to setup credentials
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1390)
```